Mechanism of Zn + NaOH?
I was reading block chemistry in class, and I was taught by my chemistry professor this method of preparation of hydrogen:

$\ce{Zn + NaOH -> Na2ZnO2 + H2}$

In this reaction, zinc reacts with sodium hydroxide base to form sodium zincate and hydrogen. This part I knew, but my professor said that the reaction proceeds as:


Zinc oxide is formed from Zn
Zinc oxide reacts with water to form $\ce{H2ZnO2}$
NaOH base reacts with the above acid to form $\ce{H2ZnO2}$


Now my doubt is that:

I have been trying to find the mechanism for this reaction, and at the same time, the acid $\ce{H2ZnO2}$ But I simply cannot find it;
Even if I assume this mechanism and this acid to even exist, then this acid should ideally dissociate like this:


$\ce{H2ZnO2 -> 2H+ + ZnO_2^{2-}}$


$\ce{NaOH -> Na+ + OH-}$

and then the reaction should proceed like

$\ce{H2ZnO2 + NaOH -> Na2ZnO2 + H2O}$

How is hydrogen being formed?
What is the exact mechanism for the reaction?

Even initial reaction is likely incorrect. Actual Na2ZnO2 was only made in 1995 https://www.degruyter.com/document/doi/10.1515/znb-1996-0515/html

To develop Mithoron's information, it can be said that the reaction of zinc with $\ce{NaOH}$ does not produce the logical and expected sodium zincate $\ce{Na2ZnO2}$ as believed without proof in the 19th and 20th century (and ad proposed by Adhway). No ! In $1995$ publication, the sodium zincate was shown to have the unexpected structure $\ce{Na10Zn4O9}$, which looks like $4$ $\ce{Na2ZnO2 + 1 Na2O}$. In a first approach, it may be produced in a succession of the following equilibriums $$\ce{Zn + H2O <=> ZnO + H2} \tag {1}$$ $$\ce{ZnO + H2O <=> H2ZnO2 <=> Zn(OH)2}  \tag{2}$$ $$\ce{4 H2ZnO2 + 10 NaOH -> Na10Zn4O9 + 9 H2O} \tag {3} $$ The trouble with the equation ($1$) is that usually zinc does not significantly react with water as in ($1$). So the two first reactions ($1$) and ($2$) are better described without molecular $ \ce{H2O}$, by using the rare $\ce{H+}$ ions produced by dissociation of water. The reactions ($1$) and ($2$) become  $$\ce{H2O <=> H+ + OH-} \tag{1'}$$ $$\ce{Zn + 2 H+ <=> Zn^{2+} + H2} \tag{1''}$$ $$\ce{Zn^{2+} + 2 OH- <=> Zn(OH)2 = H2ZnO2} \tag{2'}$$ So the production of gaseous $\ce{H2}$ in mixtures $\ce{Zn + H2O}$ is prevented by the production of insoluble $\ce{Zn(OH)2}$ which makes a protective layer on the zinc surface preventing reaction ($1''$) to proceed. This layer is dissolved by $\ce{NaOH}$ according to reaction (3), and the production of $\ce{H2}$ becomes visible and important.

Zn does react with water slowly, the principle behind galvanization. The initial redox reaction is to form H atoms and various Zn ions that are complexed with water and OH- solubilizing the salts and preventing inhibition by the products. This can be observed  by  soldering Zn to a nickel, copper or platinum cathode and watching the H2 form remotely on the more inert metal cathode. It is most likely a continuous process not stepwise altho it probably can be varied by controlling the acidity. This is how Zn-alkaline batteries work using MnOx as the oxidant instead of H2O.
